# How to update related record with parent field in VF custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, master-detail, custom-controller

What I have in my custom controller is an assignment when a user inputs a value for a certain field, the field for its parent object will update as well.

For example.

User inputs the school for a scholarship recipient through `<apex:inputField>`. Both scholarship and recipient have required fields for the `school__c` field, so I need to update the school field on the scholarship record to be dynamically the same as the school that the user inputted for `recipient__c`

What I have attempted:

```
    public with sharing class regularController {
    
    public Scholarship_Award__c sch {get;set;}
    public Recipient__c rec {get;set;}
    
    //Constructor
    public regularController(){
    sch = new Scholarship_Award__c();
    rec = new Recipient__c();
    }
    
    public void saveScholarship(){
        insert rec;
        sch.Recipient__c = rec.Id;
        sch.School__c = rec.School__r;
        insert sch;
        sch = new scholarship_award__c(Recipient__c=rec.Id);
        rec = new recipient__c(School__c=sch.School__r);
    }
}
```

Which returns the error:

`A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: School__c`

on line 18 which is the line of code that sets the `school__c` field on the recipient object to the value inputted in `scholarship_award__c`:

```
        rec = new recipient__c(School__c=sch.School__c.Id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `__c`. No need to go through the relationship:

```
rec = new recipient__c(School__c=sch.School__c);
```

If you actually needed a value from the related object, you'd use `__r` instead:

```
rec = new recipient__c(Name=sch.School__r.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you. However when I change `__c` to `__r`, it returns the following error: `Illegal assignment from School__c to Id` - `__c` seems to work OK however it needs a value from the related object

Comment: See updated code on my post

Comment: @patriciajlim Correct, `__c` or `__r.Id`. I would recommend the first method, as it's less code and CPU time.

Comment: Thanks. I am still receiving the error `Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [School]: [School]
Error is in expression '{!saveScholarship}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page testpage: Class.regularController.saveScholarship: line 15, column 1` With this setup - I have hidden the `School__c` field from `recipient__c` object, but I need to prepopulate this value in the background.

Comment: @patriciajlim you'll need to set it in your controller before saving.

Comment: Thank you. When the recipient is saved, the ID is put in as the recipient name instead of the first and last name - how can I change this?

Comment: @patriciajlim If you're using inputField/outputField, it should show the name, as opposed to if you just used inputText/outputText, which would show the ID.

Comment: I used inputField, but in my controller code I set recipient field in the scholarship award record to be the Id of the recipient I just created in the same VF page... when I check out the newly created record in my org, it's just an ID in the last name box